# Excel is frozen

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have only one file open in Excel, I added a heading to a column and saw that it was centered. I

highlighted the entire column (380 rows) and went to align all rows to the left.

The program has stopped working. I cannot delete anything nor close the program. Directions for fixing the problem come up, but the program won't let me do them. I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can always close the program.
Assuming this is windows:

1. Right click on the task bar at the bottom
2. Select "Task Manager"
3. Find Excel in the menu under Apps
4. Right click and select "End Task"

or you could reboot windows.

If this is not windows, then please specify which operating system you are using next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

`Control + Shift + Esc` to open Task Manager, you can force end the task from the list.